# Increasing a progress bar by clicking a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]The idea is that the progress bar should increase when you click the button, for example, if you click on the button `play` the `happiness` should increase.

```js
const cleanBtn = document.querySelector(".clean");
const feadBtn = document.querySelector(".fead");
const playBtn = document.querySelector(".play");



cleanBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let health = document.getElementById("myHappines");
  health.style.width = 0;
  if (health.style.width > 100 % ) {
    health.style.width = 0 % ;
    else {
      health.style.width += 10 % ;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Virtual Pet</title>
    <!--font-awesome-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" />
    <!--styles-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="sections-container">
        <div class="section1">
            <div class="pet-info">
                <ul>
                    <div id="basic">
                        <ul>Name: Elis</ul>
                        <ul>Age: 2 months</ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="health">Health
                        <div id="myProgressHealth">
                            <div id="myHealth"></div>
                        </div>
                       
                    </div>
                    <div class="hunger">Hunger
                        <div id="myProgressHunger">
                            <div id="myHunger"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="happiness">Happiness
                        <div id="myProgressHappiness">
                            <div id="myHappiness"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <button class="btn-settings">Settings</button>
        </div>
            <div class="section2"> 
                <div class="pet-interactions">
                    <ul>
                    <button class="clean">Clean</button>
                    <button class="fead">Fead</button>
                    <button class="play">Play</button>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="game-control">
                    <li id="name-input">Pet Name <input type="text"></input></li>
                    <li>Game reset button <button class="btn">Reset</button></li>
                </div>
                <div class="end-game-message">
                    <p>Goodbye</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            
    </div>
   
    <!--javascript-->
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okay, fine, so that is the _idea_ - and what is the actual _question_ / _problem_ now? Please go read [ask].

Comment: that `else` statement looks unparseable in its current syntax. The brackets are wrong.

Comment: Your snippet here currently throws a syntax error. If that was not due to someone else editing your post, but is already thrown by your original code - then go and fix that first of all.

Comment: you have a few typos and you cannot use `%` in an if statement. `%` is used as a division where you want to get a remainder. You have at least to declare the `100%` as a string by using backticks or single quotes.

Comment: @CBroe it is not caused by an edit. Caused by the usage of `%` inside a statement where it is used as a division with remainder. Because he used an integer + `%`-operator instead of a string.

Comment: "myHappiness" is not spelled the same in your JS as it is in your HTML:
 let health = document.getElementById("myHappines")
vs
 <div id="myHappiness"></div>

Comment: @flame yes, I will modify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many issues and typos in your code. Clean programming will solve them all.

1. You want a bar for which HTML has a specific tag for: `<progress>`. Use it instead of `div`s!
2. Use a `ternary conditional operator` to check if the value is 100 or below and then reset the health bar or add 10% to it:

```js
const cleanBtn = document.querySelector('.clean');

cleanBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let health = document.getElementById('myHappiness');
  health.value = (health.value === health.max) ? 0 : health.value + 10;
})
```

```html
<button class="clean">Clean</button>

<br>

<label for"myHappyness">Happiness:</label><progress id="myHappiness" value ="0" max="100"></progress>
```

The main issue with your code where the many typos. Among that was that you used `< 100 %` which will divide 100 by an undefined amount and look for the remainder. `%` is used as a calculation for a remainder (`100 % 3` = `1`) . To use `100%` in the way you intended to, you have to use it as a string.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be a better approach:

```js
var happiness = 2;

document.getElementById("demo").textContent = happiness

function increaseHappiness() {
    happiness++
    document.getElementById("demo").textContent = happiness
}
```

```html
<div>
    Happyness: <span id=demo></span>
</div>

<br>

<button onClick="increaseHappiness()">More Happy</button>
```

Comment: You're welcome. If you want a progress bar:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/progress

Comment: you should not use `innerHTML` in 2022 anymore. It is slow (DOM needs to be re-parsed) and it poses a security issue (XSS injections). Use `textContent` instead! Instead of using a `div` with a CSS rule for `inline-block` you should use a `span` in the first place or use a label and `output` for semantic reasons (and the usage of screen readers).

Answer (score 0):

the first mistake you have made that you enter integer value in
`element.style.width = 10` thats wrong you should enter string value `like this element.style width = "10%";`
the same thing about your `if(element.style.width === 100%)`
thats wrong because elment.style.width return string number not int so you compare string with number its always will return false you do that instead  `if(parseInt(health.style.width) > 100 )` parseInt is method that change string to integer if it possible. hope that usefull

```js
let playBtn = document.getElementById("playBtn");
let newWidth = 0
playBtn.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
 let health = document.getElementById("myHappiness");
  if(parseInt(health.style.width) > 100 )
     {
         health.style.width = "0%";
         newWidth = 0;
     }
 else{
           newWidth += 10;
           health.style.width = newWidth + "%"
          
     }
  
})
```

```html
<div class="sections-container">
        <div class="section1">
            <div class="pet-info">
                <ul>
                    <div id="basic">
                        <ul>Name: Elis</ul>
                        <ul>Age: 2 months</ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="health">Health
                         <div id="myProgressHealth" >
                            <div id="myHealth"></div>
                        </div>
                       
                    </div>
                    <div class="hunger">Hunger
                        <div id="myProgressHunger">
                            <div id="myHunger"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="happiness" >Happiness
                        <div id="myProgressHappiness">
                            <div id="myHappiness" style="height:10px;background:red;width:0;"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <button class="btn-settings">Settings</button>
        </div>
            <div class="section2"> 
                <div class="pet-interactions">
                    <ul>
                    <button class="clean">Clean</button>
                    <button class="fead">Fead</button>
                    <button class="play" id = "playBtn">Play</button>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="game-control">
                    <li id="name-input">Pet Name <input type="text"></input></li>
                    <li>Game reset button <button class="btn">Reset</button></li>
                </div>
                <div class="end-game-message">
                    <p>Goodbye</p>
```

Comment: you should always add a sufficient explanation of what you did and how your solution would solve the issue. Posting unexplained code makes the answer hard to read or to understand how it fixes an issue.

Comment: i think i should explain what i did, thank you for advice

Comment: `100%` does not return a "string number " in JS. `100%` is an incomplete calculation in JS (or any other language). It is not written in single or double quotes nor backticks. As such the `100` is an integer and the `5` an operator. In programming languages the `5` is used as an operator for a division to get a remainder of a division: `100 % 3 = 1`